# Unable to serve static files like css, js in django python

Tags: python, django, settings

I am very new to `django`, and gone through tutorial for many days , i have started building a small website using django and trying to serve a `css` file by arranging all the necessary settings in `settings.py` file. But unfortunately my code is unable to serve the css file, i mean the concept of serving css files is not working. I googled a lot and gone through the django main doc tutorials and made changes according to them,and still doesn't works so approached `SO` and pasted my entire code below

**Structure of project folder**

```
 personnel_blog
      |____personnel_blog
      |____manage.py  |  
                      |____media
                      |____static
                      |       |____css
                      |             |____personnel_blog_hm.css 
                      |____template 
                      |        |____home_page.html
                      |____settings.py
                      |____urls.py
                      |____views.py
                      |____wsgi.py
```

Some of my settings.py file settings are below

**settings.py**

```
import os
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DEBUG = True
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static'),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                 os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'templates')
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', 'personnel_blog.views.home_page'),
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True }),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True }),
```

)

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home_page(request):
    return render_to_response("home_page.html")
```

**home_page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/personnel_blog_hm.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <p>Hello !</p>
   <a href="/" target="_top">Home</a>
  </body> 
</html>
```

**personnel_blog_hm.css**

```
body { background-color:green; }
p {color:blue;background-color:green;padding-left:20px;}
```

So above is my code, can anyone please let me know whats wrong in the settigns.py file or other py files ?

Whether need to do any other additional settings in the above code ?

so can anyone please adjust my code and make necessary changes so that i cam move forward and make my first step in web designing ..... :)

Comment: where is the setting save?

Comment: What is the django version you are using?

Comment: @arulmr: Django version 1.4.3

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like? Does STATIC_URL have a value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/personnel_blog_hm.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

**settings**

```
PROJECT_DIR  = os.path.dirname(__file__) 

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)
```

**url**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', 'personnel_blog.views.home_page'),
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value: 
name 'static' is not defined

Comment: yeah now after importing,i am not getting the error, but css is not working as same

Comment: settings file is same in the directory where static folder exists as i have mentioned in the project structue above, yes i have edited PROJECT_DIR with your code

Comment: this is my terminal response : Django version 1.4.3, using settings 'personnel_blog.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[26/Feb/2013 11:39:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 938
[26/Feb/2013 11:39:59] "GET /css/personnel_blog_hm.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2334
[26/Feb/2013 11:40:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 938
[26/Feb/2013 11:40:01] "GET /css/personnel_blog_hm.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2334

Comment: ok I noticed now, you didn't put something in STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: these are the setting STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static'),
)

Comment: it must be staticfiles not static

Comment: I am extremely sorry i dint get you , what to do now in these situation ?

Comment: change static folder to staticfiles because Django has default static folder for collectstatic so don't name your folder as static

Comment: k i changed the static folder to staticfiles in all the settings where static exists like below STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'staticfiles'),  STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/',  STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'staticfiles'),) and i hti the browser but not working as usually

Comment: no, just change only STATICFILES_DIRS. We are not understanding here. Just change only the STATICFILES_DIRS, do not change your static and media

Comment: k i have changed as you instructed, static and media folder names remains same and changed only the STATICFILES_DIRS as (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'staticfiles'),)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25122/discussion-between-shiva-krishna-and-catherine)

Comment: catherin is it working for u ? after updating the base.html file ?, i am not seeing any result here, also i am getting 500 template does n't exist after running the server from the folder inside that has sent by you

Comment: yeah, its working on me, "background:green". did you copy all the files? because I change something in the settings and I rename the folder into staticfiles

Comment: yeah i had copied entire folder that has sent by you at some other place and run the server directly inside from it

Comment: Oh wait did you change the database settings because I change it to sqlite3

Comment: no no i dint changed anything, just copied and run the server from inside the folder personnel_blog and receiving the raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html error

Comment: DEBUG=True and change the database settings like yours.

Comment: Sorry, your getting that error because you don't have 404 template. I think I change something on the DEBUG

Comment: Yup finally it worked after changing Debug value false to true and really thanks after for supporting by sparing your time

Comment: These settings are working for css files but when i tried to insert an image in home_page.html as <img src="{% static 'images/logo.jpg' %}" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> ... its showing a broken image and when i inspected the image path using firebug the path is /static/images/log.jpg which is correct, but y i am seeing broken image ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting to

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static'),
)
```

Comment: yeah i have tried and pasted the above code, still unable to work, really not able to understand what the problem is ...

Comment: @shivakrishna Can you tell me the response from the url http://localhost:8000/static/?

Comment: This is the result for  localhost:8000/static------ A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

in `settings.py` try.

```
PROJECT_DIR  = os.path.dirname(__file__)
...
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

my `settings.py` file is usually in same directory as static directory

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to this line:

```
return render_to_response("home_page.html")
```

Django's template engine requires two things to properly render a template.

1. The template name
2. A context variable

The `context variable` is a key/value dictionary listing all of the variables available to the template.

The `render_to_response` shortcut actually accepts [two different context variable parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response).

You're missing both.

Without these variables, the template doesn't have ANY variables available to it. So your `{{ STATIC_URL }}` template variable is probably blank.

To correct, try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def home_page(request):
    return render_to_response("home_page.html", {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: :k i have tried and edited my views file with the above code and still same result(css not working body color is not changed). Sorry many are trying to help me, but this is really wierd issue that not working and frustating me actually, whether this problem will be caused due to any installation errors/problems too ?

Comment: If you've done the above, check the generated HTML and make sure that {{ STATIC_URL }} is being replaced correctly. If it is, look at what happens when you visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/ in your browser. Does it generate a 500 error?

Comment: this is the line in html <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/personnel_blog_hm.css" type="text/css"> and  reponse Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/static/

Comment: No, the HTML as seen when you visit with your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this $ python manage.py collectstatic

You can check documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/)