# Jquery path not loading in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I want to use this [pluggin](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/) for watermarking images in my django website. After following the instruction I made it work in plain html server (wampserver) after trying it in my django environment, it's not working.

HTML (wampserver)

```
html lang="en">
<title>cool</title>
<head>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/watermark.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/watermark.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
    var config = {
        "path": "images/watermark.png"};
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).watermark(config);
    });
</script>

    <img src="images/hall1.jpg" alt="" class="watermark"/>
    <img src="images/hall3.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" class="watermark"/>
    <img src="images/main.jpg" alt="" class="watermark"/>


</body>
</html>
```

The above code is working fine.

Django Environment(Not working)

```
  </head>
  <body>    
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/css/watermark.jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/css/watermark.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
    var config = {
        "path": "/media/css/watermark.png" };
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).watermark(config);
    });
  </script>

  <li><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{post.main}}" class="watermark"/> </li>
  <li><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{post.side}}" class="watermark"/> </li>
  <li><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{post.sitting}}" class="watermark"/> </li>

  </body>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: check the network tab of your browser to see the actual location of the file being requested

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081893/unable-to-serve-static-files-like-css-js-in-django-python/15082062#15082062

Comment: There is no reason to load jQuery and the jQuery plugin twice! Once is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to address your static files like your css/js files, Then you have to use [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url).

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/watermark.jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/watermark.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So the same way will be used for `watermark.png` path:

```
"path": "{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/watermark.png"
```

Also consider that [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root) where you can refer to it with [`MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url) is absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold [user-uploaded files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/) is not a right place for your assets, You should config it correctly then you will be able to address them by `STATIC_URL`.

For more on this topic:

- [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)
- [The staticfiles app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/)